# Is there a way wherein I can put my uploaded images into an html page using no database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, image-uploading

I've already created a form and have successfully uploaded a file into a directory folder. Now all that needs to happen is that the image that I've uploaded needs to appear on my html page

Below is the HTML File :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button tpye="submit" name="submit"> UPLOAD </button>
    </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Also here is my php file :

```
     <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    print_r($file);
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt= explode('.',  $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

    if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if($fileError === 0 ){
            if($fileSize < 500000000){
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;

                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;

                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                header("Location: gallery.php?uploadsuccess");

                //popup
                //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
            }

            else{
                echo "Your file is too big!";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo " Error uploading your file!";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }
    }

   ?>
```

Thanks in Advance whoever can Help me !!

Comment: Just `<img src="web_path_to_uploaded_img">`

Comment: Iterate through `uploads` directory and add path in `<img src`

Comment: but the name of the images are different every time a new image is uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PHP glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

something like

```
<?php
    $fileDestination = 'uploads/';
    foreach (glob($fileDestination."*.{jpg,jpeg,png,pdf}", GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
        var_dump($file);
    }
?>
```